# How to add tooltips to angular formly labels?

Tags: angular-formly

I want to add a button next to label which on hover shows the tooltip related to that label (as shown here [Info button next to label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh0Q0.png) ).
One approach is to create a button as a formly component and add it after each component and use css to position it next to the label. I'm looking for a better solution.
Not adding a fiddle. You can go here http://angular-formly.com/#/example/intro/introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsbin.com/qexekeg/5/edit?html,js,output

Step 1: Create wrapper

```
formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
      name: 'bootstrapLabel',
      overwriteOk: true, //as we are overwriting original bootstrapLabel wrapper
      templateUrl: 'tooltip-wrapper.html'
    });
```

Step 2: Use angular-ui-bootstrap tooltip directive in wrapper template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tooltip-wrapper.html">
  <div>
  <label for="{{id}}" class="control-label {{to.labelSrOnly ? 'sr-only' : ''}}" ng-if="to.label">
    {{to.label}}
    {{to.required ? '*' : ''}}
  </label><i ng-if="to.tooltip"
             class="control-label-help glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"
             uib-tooltip="{{to.tooltip.content}}"
             tooltip-is-open="true"></i>
  <formly-transclude></formly-transclude>
</div>
</script>
```

Step 3: Add new properties to templateOptions.

```
vm.fields = [
      {
        key: 'text',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          label: 'Text',
          placeholder: 'Formly is terrific!',
          tooltip: {
            content: "This is simple tooltip."
          }
        }
      }];
```

Extra: Add some css...

```
.control-label-help {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```